# i use sscanf to convert string to find a err

Tags: c

I have a code like next ,the messagecmdbuf is "1005 1 7 null",but when i call the sscanf ,the convert result is 1005 0 7 null.

```
char * messagecmdbuf=(char *)malloc(BUFSIZE);
char * tmp_module_mask= (char *)malloc(MININASQQIOT_MODULE_LENGTH);
int tmplogflg;
unsigned char tmp_level_mask;
int tmp=-1;
int nGUIDSize = 0;
int cmd=0;
memset(tmp_module_mask,0,MININASQQIOT_MODULE_LENGTH);
tmp=sscanf(messagecmdbuf,"%d %d %d %s",&cmd,&tmplogflg,&tmp_level_mask,tmp_module_mask);
printf("net_client_response  para---%d %d %d %d %s",tmp,cmd,tmplogflg,tmp_level_mask,tmp_module_mask);
```

linux gdb result
[image]

Comment: null means '\0'` one or written as "null" is string ?

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the symptoms of undefined behavior.

In the line:

```
tmp=sscanf(messagecmdbuf,"%d %d %d %s",&cmd,&tmplogflg,&tmp_level_mask,tmp_module_mask);
```

type of `&tmp_level_mask` is `unsigned char*` while the expected argument type is `int*`.

You can resolve this problem by:

Using the format specifier `%hhu` to read the data:

```
tmp=sscanf(messagecmdbuf,"%d %d %hhu %s",&cmd,&tmplogflg,&tmp_level_mask,tmp_module_mask);
```

or using a variable of type `int` to read the data:

```
int mask;
...

tmp=sscanf(messagecmdbuf,"%d %d %d %s",&cmd,&tmplogflg,&mask,tmp_module_mask);
```